# How to work with VideoView and fragments

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-videoview

How to work with `VideoView` and `Fragments`

```
public class Tab2 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
        Button play = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.play);
        VideoView vid = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        return rootView;
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   switch (view.getId()){
       case R.id.play:
    String videopath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.prod;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(videopath);
    vid.setVideoURI(uri);
    vid.start();
}

}
}
```

[image]

Comment: what is the error or problem you have?

Answer (score 0):

call getContext() before getPackageName, and do the click function inside on the onCreateView:

```
public class Tab2 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
        Button play = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.play);
        VideoView vid = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        rootView.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String videopath = "android.resource://" + 
                getContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.prod;
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(videopath);
                rootView.vid.setVideoURI(uri);
                rootView.vid.start();
            }
        });            
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this JavaScript function:

```
function Onselectvideo()
{    
    var openPage = "/ttk/images/Healtheaze.mp4";
    //var openPage = "/OnlineHomeAction.do"+partmeter;
    var w = screen.availWidth - 10;
    var h = screen.availHeight - 49;
    var features = "scrollbars=0,status=1,toolbar=0,top=0,left=0,resizable=0,menubar=no,width="+w+",height="+h;
    window.open(openPage,'',features);  
}
```